# Android Studio installation error "SDK emulator directory is missing"

Tags: android, android-studio

I want install **Android Studio** on a PC which have **no internet connetion**.

To do that, I download **Android Studio** on a USB key. But when I install it on **my PC** with **no connetion** it **doesn't work** and I have the message :

```
"SDK emulator directory is missing"
```

I tried to download **SDK** on **Android website**. I downloaded a file `"commandlinetools"`. But it still doesn't work.